# Airflow: Celery workers too many MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, celery, airflow

We are Running Airflow 1.10.1 with Celery. Facing multiple open connections. At the time DAGs kicks in - UI hangs for couple of minutes.

Highlights:

- All nodes are BareMetal: CPU(s):40, MHz 2494.015, RAM 378G, 10Gb NIC -
- DB connections are not being re-used
- Connections stay open while active only 5
- Workers create hundreds of connections that’s remain open until DB cleared them (900 sec)
- each worker run 100 celery threads

MySQL>  show global status like 'Thread%';

```
+-------------------------+---------     + 
| Variable_name           | Value         |
+-------------------------+---------      +
| Thread pool_idle_threads | 0            |
| Thread pool_threads      | 0            |
| Threads_cached          | 775           |
| Threads_connected       | 5323          |
| Threads_created         | 4846609       |
| Threads_running         | 5             |
+-------------------------+---------      +
```

MySQL connections:

```
31  - worker1
215 - worker2
349 - worker53
335 - worker54
347 - worker55
336 - worker56
336 - worker57
354 - worker58
339 - worker59
328 - worker60
333 - worker61
337 - worker62
2   - scheduler
```

Worker .cfg

```
[core]
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 900
sql_alchemy_reconnect_timeout = 300
parallelism = 1200
dag_concurrency = 800
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 1200
max_active_runs_per_dag = 10
dagbag_import_timeout = 30
[celery]
worker_concurrency = 100
```

Scheduler .cfg:

```
   [core]
    sql_alchemy_pool_size = 30
    sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 300
    sql_alchemy_reconnect_timeout = 300
    parallelism = 1200
    dag_concurrency = 800
    non_pooled_task_slot_count = 1200
    max_active_runs_per_dag = 10
    [scheduler]
    job_heartbeat_sec = 5
    scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
    run_duration = 1800
    min_file_process_interval = 10
    min_file_parsing_loop_time = 1
    dag_dir_list_interval = 300
    print_stats_interval = 30
    scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300
    max_tis_per_query = 1024
    max_threads = 29
```

To add, I'm running 1000 simple tasks like `sleep` or `ls`

Comment: you said you are using dynamic dags.  can you show us a typical "dynamic" dag?  does the "dynamic" part involve a database call?
You say "facing multiple open connections".  To which database?  Airflow metastore DB? you wrote `CPU(s):40` are you saying that every worker machine 40cpus?

Comment: you have given your workers a _lot_ of capacity; have you scaled the database commensurately?

Comment: Are you sure you have identical `airflow.cfg` across all machines? The [docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/configuration.html#scaling-out-with-celery) say `..Airflow configuration settings should be homogeneous across the cluster..`. Also I notice that `worker_concurrency = 100` is quite high; quoting [astronomer.io docs](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-scaling-workers/) `..it determines how many tasks a single worker can process..`

Comment: I have done testings on static dags and we have changed logic in dynamic, too. but it did not do any better.

Comment: does the "dynamic" part involve a database call? It does , we were able to reduce about 10% by changing the logic, but still I see a lot of them coming. For example, I just launched 1.10.4 and from a host(scheduler, worker(100)) got 400 connections where static DAGs were running

Comment: @y2k-shubham I do not have identical `cfg`, however, it just varies for sql_alchemy and celery threads, which should not be the case. 100 - is should not be that hight for the hardware we are running on and we are planning to triple the numbers if possible.

Answer (score 3):

We were able to drop connections to 1-10 from 700-800

Two things you can do:

1. set `sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = False`
2. setup a different `result_backend` from DB, in our case we used redis as `result_backend` and MySQL as primary DB

Comment: Why do you set `sql_alchemy_pool_enabled=False` ? I think that pool_enabled=True will be more flexible to multiple meta db connection